# Incorrect value of enum variable

Tags: c++, enums

I just began a little fun project which is good ol' snake in CLI. What I'm currently figuring out is changing directions of a single dot inside a box (no snake yet!). I created an enum type with values up, down etc. and created a simple loop to update the position. What's curious is that no matter what value I assign to the direction variable, it is always 3 (DOWN). Here's working example:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
bool gameOver;
const int width = 60;
const int height = 20;
int x, y, fruitX, fruitY, score;

enum eDirection {STOP, LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN};
enum eDirection dir;

int modulo(int x,int N){
    return (x % N + N) %N;
}

void Setup(){
    gameOver = false;
    dir = LEFT;
    x = width / 2;
    y = height / 2;
    fruitX = rand() % width;
    fruitY = rand() % height;
    score = 0;
}

void Draw(){

    system("cls");

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++){
        cout << "#";
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        cout << "#";
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++){

            if (j == x && i == y){
                cout << "O";
            }
            else{
            cout << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << "#";
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++){
        cout << "#";
    }
    cout << endl;

    if (dir = STOP){
        
    } else if (dir = UP){
        y = modulo((y - 1) , height);
    } else if (dir = DOWN){
        y = modulo((y + 1) , height);
    } else if (dir = LEFT){
        x = modulo((x - 1) , width);
    } else if (dir = RIGHT){
        x = modulo((x + 1) , width);
    }


}

void Input(){

}

void Logic(){

}

int main()
{
    Setup();
    while(!gameOver)
    {
        Draw();
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Direction value is: ";
        cout << dir;
        Input();
        Logic();
        //Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Any ideas? I'm fairly new to C++ and it's still difficult for me to get my head around some of its concepts.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator in C++. You should use `==` operator to check equality. Also `DOWN` should be 4, not 3.

Comment: Hi @MikeCAT, I think we agree on the operators, but what do u mean by your last sentence please? :)

Comment: Using this definition `enum eDirection {STOP, LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN};` `STOP` should be `0`, `LEFT` should be `1`, `RIGHT` should be `2`, `UP` should be `3`, and `DOWN` should be `4`. Thus I said `DOWN` should be 4, not 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
if (dir = STOP)
```

to:

```
if (dir == STOP)
```

since you want to **compare** those two, *not* assign `UP` to `dir`. Same change is required for your other conditions in the else-if statements.

Tip: Enable compiler warnings in order to get informed about those pesky logical errors. For example in GCC, you could use the useful all warnings flag (Wall), like this:

```
gcc -Wall snake.c -o snake
```

to get:

```
54:19: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
56:24: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
58:26: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
60:26: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
62:27: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
```

where the the numbers at the start of each warning is in format `line:column`, allowing you to find the line of code that emits the warning, and also the column at that line.

Comment: Right... thank you. It's quite amazing how you can sit at home in front of your computer and find help literally immediately in such trivial matters. Walking to the nearest living neighbor would actually take me longer.

Comment: @Filemon Turn on compiler warnigs; gcc, clang can definitely detect these errors.

Comment: @Quimby learn a man to fish, great comment, I updated my answer! :)

Comment: @Quimby thanks for the compiler warnings tip, I'll give it a try.